# Can VeraCrypt open an old TrueCrypt container?

Tags: truecrypt, veracrypt

I have a TrueCrypt container that was made some time in 2013. It's exactly 25MB and named `secret.tc`. I installed VeraCrypt 1.19 in macOS Sierra, but cannot seem to mount the container.

The error in the VeraCrypt GUI is:

```
Operation failed due to one or more of the following:

- Incorrect password.
- Incorrect Volume PIM number.
- Incorrect PRF (hash).
- Not a valid volume.
```

Looking through the `--help` I do seem to recognize the word `nokernelcrypto`, but not why. It's been quite a few years.

I have attempted both with and without TrueCrypt Mode enabled. Are there compatibility issues?

Comment: Yes; Yes it can;  It appears you are providing the incorrect password or the volume is no longer valid.  If it's critical data use the last version of Truecrypt released and see if it will mount, if it does, duplicate the data into a VeraCrypt container

Comment: Are you actually sure that you're using the correct password etc. to mount it?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately VeraCrypt has discontinued support for TrueCrypt volumes as of version 1.26.7 (October 1st, 2023). I can confirm that with the latest version of VeraCrypt I am no longer able to open TC volumes and there is no longer an option for "TrueCrypt Mode". They are now officially recommending an older version to access TC volumes.

> Starting from version 1.26.7, VeraCrypt discontinued support for the TrueCrypt format to prioritize the highest security standards. However, recognizing the transitionary needs of our users, we have preserved version 1.25.9, the last to support the TrueCrypt format.
>
> On this page, users can find download links for version 1.25.9, specifically provided for converting TrueCrypt volumes to the more secure VeraCrypt format. We strongly recommend transitioning to VeraCrypt volumes and using our latest releases for ongoing encryption needs, as they encompass the latest security enhancements.

https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads_1.25.9.html

Comment: A transition period with read-only support would have been nice :|

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same issue and just to re-confirm what others are saying - Veracrypt can sometimes fail in opening older TC volumes. To fix this just download an older version of TC and migrate to a compatible VC volume.

Edit: Just to clarify this should only be an issue you have a volume created with a version of TC <6. So if you created the volume with say v5 of TrueCrypt you would not be able to open that volume, and you should see a message like such:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm Vera crypt won't open some of the containers created by True crypt.
I've some containers from about 2005 and 2006, which I recently recovered from old CD backup discs, which failed to mount in Vera crypt (true crypt mode enabled)
I tried for hours using variation of the password I may have used, always ended up in error.
Today I have got a copy of true crypt v7 and installed it in windows xp virtual machine, and presto, works straight away!! 
So don't give up on your old TC volumes, just try with latest version of true crypt (7.1 I think was the latest).

Comment: Hi, I had to use the same solution vm+truecrypt installation to open volume that was created with TrueCrypt 7.0a.

Answer (score 2):

Just to distill the content here & provide my experience - yes - really old volumes of TrueCrypt CAN NOT be opened by VeraCrypt.

It it's important, get the last version of TrueCrypt (7.2), decrypt or mount those volumes in TrueCrypt, create a suitably sized & secure empty VeraCrypt volume, copy all your recovered TrueCrypt files into the new Veracrypt volume, and you are done.

Could there be problems? Perhaps, but I've done this with no problems with TrueCrypt volumes created over a decade ago. If you are worried about security breaches, sandbox the TrueCrypt & volume to decode into clear text, unistall TrueCrypt, create a suitable VeraCrypt volume, copy decoded cleartext you got from the old TrueCrypt volume, into the new VeraCrypt volume, delete both the clear text and the TC volume, & now you should be pretty much converted & good to go

Bottom line is if you have some really old TrueCrypt volumes you wold like to recover, your options are basically give up, or do the one time port with original TrueCrypt, import them into your new VeraCrypt volumes, then delete TrueCrypt & those volumes from your system. No guarantees, but that probably the most reasonable compromise if you ever want to see those old files again.

Oh, & PS - just for extra care, copy the .tc file you want to decrypt. If something goes terribly wrong & it gets corrupted, you still have the originaL.

Answer (score 1):

You would have no problems to mount `TrueCrypt` container from `VeraCrypt` application - with or without the `TrueCrypt` check box checked.

So you problem is probably with *entering an incorrect password* or *entering a PIM* (you must *not* to enter it) or with the corrupted file (if you have a backup of it try it).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. I have volumes from 3.x encrypted with Whirlpool by a simple password, and Veracrypt will not mount them no matter what, even in TC mode. An old copy of TC 6 mounts them just fine.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you don’t know how to do it.   And I don’t know how to speak Chinese.   Do you have any evidence that it *cannot be done* other than your inability to find a way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

I came to this post because it appeared that VC had corrubpted two TC volumes even after restarting. So, I created another post about that issue. I want to answer that contrary to @MarianD's response, yes VC can open an old TC container and the "TrueCrypt Mode" *must* be checked as in the instructions for converting volumes from the VC site below. (provided that it is not too old as @DenjinJ points out). I just tested without it checked and it will not mount, giving the generic error seen above.

https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Converting%20TrueCrypt%20volumes%20and%20partitions.html

[How do I recover Truecrypt volume that Veracrypt corrupted?](https://superuser.com/questions/1303808/how-do-i-recover-truecrypt-volume-that-veracrypt-corrupted)